# Posts 2 posts plugin loop echo the_title not working

Tags: plugins

I have a basic loop (a rough example of what I'm doing) of work, and want to show the client(s) the work was done for. Some work has clients connected and some doesn't. The work that doas have one or more client associated with it echos the clients paragraph, and echos it once for each connect client, so it is recognizing the connections. But it doesn't echo the title, and I cant't seem to figure out why.

This is taken straight from the Posts 2 Posts github:
https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'work'
) );

p2p_type( 'work_for_client' )->each_connected( $my_query, array(), 'clients' );


while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php
    // Display connected clients


    foreach ( $post->clients as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<p>clients:</p>';
        echo the_title();

    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

Comment: What does `$post->client` look like? Unless it is an array of WordPress post objects (so that each `$post` is a post object) I doubt `the_title` is going to work. Looks like you are probably clobbering `$post` a couple of different times as well.

Comment: $post->client doesn't work because the post type is clients, but I tried it anyway.

I took this straight from the Posts 2 Posts git page:
https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code? In a function? Somewhere in a template?

`setup_postdata` does not replace the global `$post` with the `$post` object passed in. It does, however, modify some other globals.

So if you're trying to use the various `the_*` template tags, you need to explicitly replace the global `$post` object on which they depend.

In a function, for example...

```
<?php
function wpse73103_loop_example()
{
    global $post; // this is important!

    $posts = new WP_Query(/* your args here */);

    // because $post is global above, this will
    // overwrite the global object.
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post);
        // do stuff
    }

    wp_reset_postdata(); // back to normal
}
```

Anyway, the moral of the story is that you should try putting `global $post;` before any of the code you posted (which is very much correct).

Comment: This is in a template and isn't a function. It's using the posts 2 posts plugin, so that extra query-ing is important. But I tried adding global $post; to the top and that didn't work. However I am able to get wp_alchemy meta but not a basic thing like the_title so I think your right, I just gotta figure out how to apply it to this specific code.

Comment: If all else fails you can use something like [`get_post_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field). You can also try doing `$GLOBALS['post'] = $post;` inside your foreach loop.